# Getting a date string for file name in batch file with sqlcmd

Tags: sql, batch-file

I managed to get the desired file name but the data is unformatted. The output file is without delimiter ","

```
rem @echo off
set currdate=currdate.tmp
DATE /T > %currdate%

set parsearg="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
for /f %parsearg% %%i in (%currdate%) do (set mmddyyyy=%%j%%k%%l& set MTH=%%j& set DOW=%%i& set DAY=%%k& set YEAR=%%l)


set day=%DAY%
set mth=%MTH%
set year=%YEAR%
set TODAY=%year%%mth%%day%

sqlcmd -i F_ST_PROMOTION.sql -o F_ST_PROMOTION.%TODAY%.csv
```

output file name (success)
F_ST_PROMOTION.20140115.csv

Anyone has any idea for this?

Thanks Much

Comment: I don't understand. What is you current output, and what is your desired output?

Comment: BTW wouldn't `SET TODAY=%date:~-4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%` be more straightforward?

Comment: You're not specifying a column separator. add `-s ","` to your sqlcmd line.